# Unit test Angular router event on Activationstart

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Need some help regarding writing test case for the below mentioned code. The problem is, I am not able to mock `ActivationStart`. I am using angular 10.

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof ActivationStart)
  )
  .subscribe((event) => {
    this.breadCrumb = this.getBreadCrumb(event);
    // other logics here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of `RouterTestingModule`

Try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dummy',
  template: '<div>Hello</div>,
  styleUrls: [],
})
class DummyComponent {}
describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let router: Router;
   
  // waitForAsync is async in older versions of Angular
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DummyComponent,
        // your other declarations here
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: 'dummy', component: DummyComponent },
        ]),
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
     
     router = TestBed.inject(Router); // TestBed.inject should be TestBed.get in older versions of Angular
     // wait for the initialNavigation of the router
     // I think this should be enough to trigger that event you require
     router.initialNavigation();
  }));

  it('should trigger the event', async () => {
     // this explicit navigation should trigger the event
     await router.navigate('dummy');
     // assert the breadcrumb
     expect(component.breadCrumb).toBe(...);

  });

});
```